# Login Processing Url

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've noticed that many people configure Spring Security's `form-login` as follows

```
<form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login"     
authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
```

The default `login-processing-url` is `/j_spring_security_check` so why change it by adding `/static`?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of functionality there is no difference. It is just that the Spring framework is very flexible and lets you change the various configuration easily. It can be useful when you want to hide the fact that you are using Spring Security, by changing to a different url (without Spring it it).

Answer (score 0):

Adding To Umesh's answer  and quoting it from Spring Security Book

> It may be obvious, but if we only wanted to add a custom login page, we would only need to specify the login-page attribute. We would then create our login form using the default values for the remaining attributes. However, it is often a good practice to override the values of anything visible to users, to prevent exposing that we are using Spring Security. Revealing what frameworks we are using is a type of "information leakage", making it easier for attackers to determine potential holes in our security.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still intrested using login processing URL we can change the default URL. so in case you have patterns defined in http tags at that time j_spring_security will fail. So it is really useful when we are restricting according to pattern.